# Modify a local JS-file using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

### Information

For testing purposes I am building a system where a javascript file contains an array called "contains".

The javascript will then make the browser redirect to another page where the php-code is located, and that code should add the keyword as a new array-element

> And before anyone of you try to say how simple this is, let me reiterate that I am injecting the JS code on another page using Tampermonkey, and I have no chance to modify their code

The code should then be converted to JS again and be written to a file which is called "copyright.js"

### Code

At the moment the "copyright.js" file looks like this

```
var contains = ["original"]
```

The following code returns a positive result

```
$str = 'var contains = ["original"]';
$str = str_replace("var ", '$', $str); 
eval($str.";");
```

But when I try to fetch the variable from the file i get an error

```
$file = fopen('copyright.js', 'r') or die('Unable to open File');
$str = fread($file, filesize('copyright.js'));
fclose($file);
$str = str_replace("var ", '$', $str); 
eval($str.";");
```

If there is a better solution to this, please don't hesitate to tell me :)

Comment: Are you trying to run `eval()` in PHP on a string containing javascript?

Comment: Can you try your solution with `$str = file_get_contents('copyright.js');`?

Comment: If you already have a php backend, can you put the data into a database instead of updating a physical file? You'll need a php script to read the data.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes

Comment: PHP can't parse and eval JS... the only reason why your script doesn't fail is because it reads it as PHP (`$contains = ["original"];` is a valid PHP statement). You just created a PHP array but it has nothing to do with JS (this runs on the server and never returned to the client as javascript).

Comment: @DaveChen Does not work

Comment: Does it have an error output? `print_r($contains);` will properly show what you expect it to show. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: ...and you need to tell us what the error your getting is. Otherwise, we don't know what we are trying to solve.

Comment: I read your question again and you don't have code for saving the array back. You need to make the array yourself then use `file_put_contents` to save it back.

Comment: `But when I try to fetch the variable from the file i get an error` What error?

Comment: Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$contains' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\www\gallery\other_stuff\addTag.php(18) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: again.. PHP's `eval()` evaluates PHP, _NOT_ js

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So is there a way to do this another way?

Comment: I actually don't really understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to read the JS-file, modify it with PHP and return the modified string to the client as JS? Then instead of eval(), first send a header with "application/javascript" and then just echo the modified string. Then include that php-file in your HTML with: `<script src="path/to/file.php"></script>`.

Comment: Maybe PHP is not the best option to do this. Maybe Node.JS ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I actually dont have access to the backend of the site, It's owned by someone else. All I am trying to do is to fetch a word (with i select by injecting the site with tampermonkey-javascript), and then i want the string to be added to a local .js file as text in the array. The local file is stored on my own computer, which is the only reason I am using php and JS instead of just JS...

Comment: If you don't have access to the back end, how are you then gonna run your PHP to parse the file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am using a local php-server to run the one php-file I need, which is stored in the same folder as the "copyright.js" file

Comment: @MathiasNervik then there's no reason why you can't run a locally hosted Node.JS